# How do I create a UIPickerView-like picker from scratch?

Tags: ios, xcode, uipickerview

I've looked into customizing the `UIPickerView`, but the options to customize it the way I want to do not exist.

I want to change the "selection highlight" to be a static image *behind* the text labels rather than a static transparent image above it like with the default UI. I also want to take off the gradient overlay on the top and bottom of the dial.

Does anyone here have any tips on creating a custom picker from scratch or possibly subclassing a `UIPickerView` to do what I want?

Answer (score 1):

Subclassing `UIPickerView` won't really help you because it'll be just one big hack, since it's appearance can't be changed. You can try using `UIScrollView` with paging for the rolling part, and set it's background to `clearColor` so your selection highlight will be visible.